# Can I submit an oozie job with multiple configuration files?

Tags: hadoop, configuration-files, oozie

From the Oozie CLI I want to do something like this:

```
oozie job -oozie http://host:port/oozie -config jobConfig.properties, baseConfig.properties -submit
```

I have a lot of different jobs I'm running where a portion of the .properties file is identical.  I'd like to be able to move that duplicated portion into a single baseConfig.properties file, and combine this with the job-specific part when I submit the job.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the number of overridden properties is small, you can just reference the base config file, and then use the `-Dprop1=value` notation for each property you want to customize.

Otherwise i think you have two (possibly three) alternatives (as you can't pass multiple config options to the current OOZIE client):

1. Create a script that concatenates the base and job specific property files together, and the run oozie with the name of the merged file
2. Using the source from [OozieCLI](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/oozie/trunk/client/src/main/java/org/apache/oozie/cli/OozieCLI.java?view=markup) as a starting point, write an extension class that can handle a CSV value for the `-config` option, or can handle multiple `-config` argument instances
3. Are you able to move the common attributes into static jobXml files for each action, then you would only need a single config file for the actual differences between the job runs.

Comment: Thanks, Chris.  I was kind of suspecting I would have to make my build script concatenate the two files, but you've given me a bunch of other good options.

Comment: @TimGoodman what did you wind up doing?  I have a similar use case.

Answer (score 3):

I could put default values into config-default.xml file as desribed here:
http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.1_Workflow_Job_Properties_or_Parameters

It works in most of cases.